# WPF/Windows Forms Host on Windows7

Tags: wpf, opengl, windows-7, xamlparseexception, windowsformshost

I have a crash that's happening on Windows7 but not on XP, and was hoping for some insight.

The application has an OpenGL Windows Form control used to display 16 bit grayscale images.  This control works well under XP, and has been wrapped with a WindowsFormHost to run under WPF.  When I start the application in Windows 7, the application crashes with a generic error stating that the WindowsFormHost crashed on creation.

Is this form of windows forms hosting broken on Windows 7?

EDIT: it's listed as an `XAMLParseException`, for what that's worth.

Comment: What version of .NET is you application targeted at? What versions of .NET are installed? You can check by looking in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework

Comment: 3.5 sp1-- and it's installed, or at least, 3.5 is.

Comment: The XamlParseException is just a wrapper of the real problem.  You'll need to dig through all of the .InnerException properties until you can find the real culprit.